# Deriving Two Tissue Compartment Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a known function $c_p(t)$ and that $$ \frac{dc_1(t)}{dt} = k_1 c_p(t) - (k_2 + k_3) c_1(t) + k_4 c_2(t) $$ $$ \frac{dc_2(t)}{dt} = k_3 c_1(t) - k_4 c_2(t) $$ $$c(t) = c_1(t) + c_2(t) $$ what are the steps to obtain
$$ \frac{d^2c(t)}{dt} = k_1 \frac{dc_p(t)}{dt} + k_1(k_3 + k_4)c_p(t) - (k_2 + k_3 + k_4) \frac{dc(t)}{dt} - k_2k_4 c(t) \quad?$$

I've read through the literature (in the context of compartment models related to FDG), but all of it fails to offer any explanation to its derivation. A reference would suffice as an answer, but I haven't been able to find one.

**References**

Cai W, Feng D, Fulton R, Siu WC: Generalized linear least squares algorithms for modeling glucose metabolism in the human brain with corrections for vascular effects. Comput Methods Programs Biomed 2002, 68(1):1-14.

D. Feng, S.C. Huang, Z. Wang, D. Ho, An unbiased
parametric imaging algorithm for non-uniformly sampled
biomedical system parameter estimation, IEEE Trans.
Med. Imag. 15 (1996) 512–518

Comment: Can you post a reference for the last equation? Also, there's a typo in the last term of that equation, a stray ")".

Comment: As a starter you can look at this Cai W, Feng D, Fulton R, Siu WC: Generalized linear least squares algorithms for modeling glucose metabolism in the human brain with corrections for vascular effects. Comput Methods Programs Biomed 2002, 68(1):1-14. But even if you dig further into the citations and citations of citations it's the same thing... No derivation.

Comment: To be clear I'm interested in going from the first three equations to the last one, and not using the closed form solution to obtain the second order differential. This is important for me because $k_3$ is time dependent in my case

Answer (score 0):

It seems I finally came around to finding the proper sequence of substitutions...

From the first three equations we have 
$$c'(t) = k_1 c_p(t) - k_2 c_1(t)$$
$$c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_2 c_1'(t)$$
$$c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_2(k_1 c_p(t) - (k_2 + k_3)c_1(t) + k_4 c_2(t))$$
$$c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_1k_2 c_p(t) + k_2(k_2 + k_3) c_1(t) - k_2k_4 c_2(t)$$
$$c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_1 k_2 c_p(t) + k_2(k_2 + k_3) c_1(t) - k_2 k_4 c(t) + k_2 k_4 c_1(t)$$
$$c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_1 k_2 c_p(t) + k_2(k_2 + k_3 + k_4) c_1(t) - k_2 k_4 c(t)$$
Now given that from the first equation $$c_1(t) = \frac{k_1 c_p(t) - c'(t)}{k_2}$$
we have
$$ c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_1 k_2 c_p(t) + (k_2 + k_3 + k_4)(k_1 c_p(t) - c'(t)) - k_2 k_4 c(t) $$

$$ c''(t) = k_1 c_p'(t) - k_1 (k_3 + k_4) c_p(t) - (k_2 + k_3 + k_4)c'(t) - k_2 k_4 c(t)$$
which is the answer.